# problem with column name with uppercase in application code

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

We are migrating applications from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. All the tables and columns are defined in lowercase. Trying to migrate all the programs that worked with SQL Server, we get an error with the columns names. In our code, the columns are specified with the first letter in Uppercase, and the queries are written with double-quote.

Here is an example of code :

```
select * from flightcost.flight where "Flightid" = 5;

ERROR:  column "Flightid" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from flightcost.flight where "Flightid" = 5;
                                          ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "flight.flightid".
SQL state: 42703
Character: 39
```

Correcting all programs ("Flightid" to "flightid") will take a lot of time.

Comment: If the tables and columns are defined in lowercase then your query will not work. If you remove your double quotes, does it run ?

Comment: Just remove the double quotes, `where Flightid = 5` will work just fine.

Comment: Yes Philippe... but this is exactly my problem... we have thousand of code lines to correct...